# Cell size in Mosaic to New Raster versus Resample cell size

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dem, mosaic, resampling

I have several TIF 2 meter LIDAR DEM files (100+) that I am merging into a single raster and then creating 4m, 6m, 10m, and 30m DEM raster variants.

I would normally just use the Mosaic to New Raster tool and not specify a cell size, maintaining 2 meters and then use the resample tool to downgrade the 2 meter DEM to the variants of 2,4,6,10,and 30 meters.

There is a Cell Size (optional) within the Mosaic to New Raster tool. If I input my 100+ 2 meter DEM files and then select a cell size of 4,6,10... etc., does this tool resample the DEM?

I am not clear on what this field does if I am creating a lower resolution raster from a higher resolution. If it does resample, what method is used since I cannot specify?

It seems I am safer now just Resampling. I would love to learn/understand more and save myself a step.

I have researched this, but I come across questions and answers around merging DEMS but not specifically addressing my question.

I am using ArcMap 10.1. There are 100+ TIF DEM files that are 2 meter cell size. 32 bit float and 1 band. Not sure if any of that is needed.

Comment: Mosaic 1 raster to new raster with 4 m cell size and compare it with resample result of different resampling. This will answer your q and perhaps take less time than q typing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the tool resamples the DEM.

You can spesify the resampling method in the Environments-parameters, under the options for Raster Storage.

As "Nearest" is the preset, I would assume this to be the standard resampling method unless otherwise spesifiyed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"..does this tool resample the DEM?"

Yes, it does the resample after it mosaics the rasters in the native cell size.

"If it does resample, what method is used since I cannot specify?"

You should be able to specify the method in the environment settings.

I like to use the resampling parameter in this tool if I'm mosaic'ing a large DEM, so I save the extra step of having to run the resample tool afterwards. If you can get your hands on ArcGIS Pro you can leverage the 'Parallel Processing' environment (I dont think this is available in the ArcMap version of the tool) to speed up the process.